# Three.js suppress write to zbuffer for one object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to suppress a write to the **z-buffer** for one object in **three.js**.

My code is:

```
mesh.onBeforeRender = function(renderer){renderer.context.depthMask(false)};
mesh.onAfterRender = function(renderer){renderer.context.depthMask(true)};
```

Seems simple enough but...
The renderer argument is not there - should be the first element of the arguments list.
In fact, the arguments is an empty array.
And... `onAfterRender` is not even called.
But... the source code for `renderObjects` looks fine to me.

What am I missing???

Comment: Try `mesh.material.depthWrite = false`, instead. Or, if you want to use `onBeforeRender()`,  `renderer.state.setDepthWrite( false )`.

Comment: That was perfect!

Comment: Do they both work for you? If so, I will post an answer.

Comment: Hi - The first works, the second does not. The onBeforeRender does not even seem to get called, though the onAfterRender does.

Comment: The posted answer is the standard way of handling your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to suppress rendering to the depth buffer, use this pattern:

```
mesh.material.depthWrite = false;
```

three.js r.83